# How to remove extension dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to remove extension dates in SQL server?

```
FileName                 | id
-------------------------+---
c:\abc_20181008.txt      | 1
c:\xyz_20181007.dat      | 2 
c:\abc_xyz_20181007.dat  | 3
c:\ab.xyz_20181007.txt   | 4
```

Based on above data I want output like below :

Table: emp

```
FileName           | id
-------------------+---
c:\abc.txt         | 1
c:\xyz.dat         | 2
c:\abc_xyz.dat     | 3
c:\ab.xyz.txt      | 4
```

I have tried like this:

```
select 
    substring (Filename, replace(filename, '.', ''), len(filename)), id  
from 
    emp
```

But this query is not returning the expected result in SQL Server.

Please tell me how to write a query to achieve this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Third time this question has been asked - twice on [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3c88c053-c427-4a82-9284-69828aa509fa/how-to-remove-extension-dates-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, filename, 
       LEFT(filename, LEN(filename) - i1) + RIGHT(filename, i2 - 1)
FROM emp
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(filename)) AS i1,
           PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(filename)) AS i2
) AS x
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6b847/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
declare @t table (a varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('c:\abc_20181008.txt')
insert into @t values ('c:\abc_xyz_20181007.dat')
insert into @t values ('c:\ab.xyz_20181007.txt')
insert into @t values ('c:\ab.xyz_20182007.txt')
select replace(SUBSTRING(a,1,CHARINDEX('2',a) - 1) + SUBSTRING(a,len(a)-3,LEN(a)),'_.','.') from @t
```

Comment: Hi  this  record is not giving expected resutl: insert into @t values ('c:\ab.xyz_19982007.txt'). here :  this condition is failed CHARINDEX('2',a)  due to file years comes 19 years also. example:

Comment: can you please tell me how to get exact result if years 1998 or 2018